# Filter items from boost::lockfree::spsc_queue

Tags: boost, queue

I use the boost::lockfree::spsc_queue to send stream data from a thread to a working thread.

These is the struct of the items:

```
struct spsc_queue_item
{
    uint8_t ID;
    void *data;
};
```

The data get insert by spsc_queue.push and read by the other thread by spsc_queue.pop.

But I also have some "commands" for the worker thread.
Like ID 0 is "start filter",
ID 1 is "stop filter",
ID 2 id "data"...

So if a lot of "data" get pushed to the queue the command like "stop filter" will be delayed because first the "data" items are handled.
But if the command "stop filter" is coming in the "data" items are useless and can be discarded.

Now I know there is also the member function "consume_one" and "consume_all".

But I don't find a example how to use the functor with these functions.
My idea is to use as example consume_one to check first if a item with ID==0 or ID==1 is on the queue before continue working with the data items with ID==2.

Somebody have a small example how to use the functor to filter out items releated to the requested ID?

Or is there any other fast way to get items from the queue by a "priority" flag?

**UPDATE** In response to sehe's answer, some more information:

---

Thank you for this information.

Any idea how to make it better?

I will need to signal the worker thread like for "start filter", "stop filter",...

I was thinking of using events:

```
SetEvent(hStartFilter);
```

But here I have to use, create and close for each command a single event.

The "data" can also have different IDs.
Like the worker thread receives:

```
"start filter" with ID=0
"start filter" with ID=1
```

Then "data" with ID0 and ID1 is coming into the queue.
Now the thread receives "stop filter" with ID0.
So all items on the data-queue with ID0 are obsolete and can be deleted.

My first test was to grap all items from the queue. Check each of them of the matching ID and remove the item. The other items what are left are getting pushed back to the queue after.
But this is a lot of CPU usage and time consuming action if there are a lot of data with different IDs (up to 32). The maximum size of the queue is 2048 items.

Is there also a better way?

Comment: What are you using this for? If you are multiplexing asynchronous network events consider using Boost Asio. It has all the queue and dispatch logic built in

Answer (score 0):

Queues have FIFO semantics. There's no way to filter, unless you want to *just discard* elements that don't match your criteria. (Just wrap the `pop` function)

The typical solution to this is to use

- a priority queue
- two separate queues, one for data and one for commands.

If you can never have more than *x* elements in the data queue, consider using a circular buffer. `spsc_queue` uses a ring buffer as the underlying storage.

**UPDATE** In response to the [question edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34766287/revisions), I decided to create a demo using out-of-band signaling of filtering-state per ID.

Let me walk through, starting with the usual definitions:

```
static constexpr uint8_t NUM_SOURCES = 32;
```

Now, the common definitions shared by both the constumer and the producer:

```
namespace queueing {
    using data_t = std::vector<char>; // just for demo

    struct spsc_queue_item {
        uint8_t ID;
        data_t  data;
    };

    // process control
    boost::atomic_bool shutdown_flag { false };

    namespace statistics {
        namespace events {
            boost::atomic_size_t occurred  { 0 };
        }

        namespace packets {
            boost::atomic_size_t queued    { 0 };
            boost::atomic_size_t dropped   { 0 };
            boost::atomic_size_t processed { 0 };
            boost::atomic_size_t skipped[NUM_SOURCES] = {};
        }

        boost::atomic_size_t idle_cycles   { 0 };

        void report();
    }

    // business logic
    boost::atomic_bool   source_enabled  [NUM_SOURCES] = {}; // true:started (process) / false:stopped (skip)
    boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<spsc_queue_item, boost::lockfree::capacity<2048> > shared_queue;
}
```

As you can see I changed data (because it's easier to demo without the `void*`). Also, I added a number of useful statistics that can be `report()`-ed at the end of your rest runs.

```
void producer_thread() {
    using namespace boost;
    namespace stats = queueing::statistics;
    // helpers to generate random data packets or start/stop filter events

    enum kind_t { knd_data, knd_start, knd_stop };
    queueing::data_t const empty {};
    struct event_t { kind_t kind; spsc_queue_item item; };
    // ...

    // now generate queue items in a loop
    while (!queueing::shutdown_flag) {
        auto evt = gen_event();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(engine()%102400));

        switch(evt.kind) {
            case knd_data:
                stats::events::occurred++;

                if (queueing::shared_queue.push(evt.item)) {
                    stats::packets::queued++;
                } else {
                    stats::packets::dropped++;
                }
                break;
            case knd_start: {
                    bool expected = false;
                    if (queueing::source_enabled[evt.item.ID].compare_exchange_weak(expected, true))
                        std::cout << "+";// << static_cast<int>(evt.item.ID);
                }
                break;
            case knd_stop: {
                    bool expected = true;
                    if (queueing::source_enabled[evt.item.ID].compare_exchange_weak(expected, false))
                        std::cout << "-";// << static_cast<int>(evt.item.ID);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The body of the thread function is quite straight-forward, but a notable thing is that `start` and `stop` events are not communicated over the queue.

The producer is even simpler. All it does is exhaust the queue, updating some statistics counters.
Before processing an item, the corresponding filtering state (`source_enabled`) is checked:

```
void consumer_thread() {
    namespace stats = queueing::statistics;

    queueing::spsc_queue_item item;

    auto consume_pending = [&] {
        while (queueing::shared_queue.pop(item)) {
            if (queueing::source_enabled[item.ID])
                fake_process(item); // if filtering started, process 
            else
                stats::packets::skipped[item.ID]++; // if filtering stopped, skip 
        }
    };

    while (!queueing::shutdown_flag) {
        consume_pending();
        stats::idle_cycles++;
    }

    consume_pending(); // drain any remaining queued items, to avoid race with shutdown_flag
}
```

Now, everything should be self-explanatory so, piece together a `main()` function:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std;

    // check no source_enabled flags are set at start
    assert(0 == count(begin(queueing::source_enabled), end(queueing::source_enabled), true));

    auto producer = thread(producer_thread);
    auto consumer = thread(consumer_thread);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    queueing::shutdown_flag = true;

    if (producer.joinable()) producer.join();
    if (consumer.joinable()) consumer.join();

    queueing::statistics::report();
}
```

Our program runs both threads for approximately 1 second and waits for them join.
Then it reports statistics which, on my system, look like:

```
++-+++++++--+++-++++-++-+++---+-+-+-+++++-+--+---+++-++---+-++-++-+-+++---++--+++-++---+----+-+-+-+--+++-++--+--+--++--+-+-+-+--+--+++--++-+-++-++-+--+--+++-++-+---+----++-+++-+-++-+----+--+-+-+--+++--+++++-+-+--++-+--++++-+-+---++-+---+-+--++---++++----+-+---+-+-+-+--+-++--+-+++--+++-+----+-+-+-+++-+++--+-++-++++++---++--+-++-++---+-+-++--+-+-----++---+-+-+--+++--++---++--+-+++-++++-+++-+-+--+++-+-+----+-++++-+--+++----+++-------+-++-+-+-++++-++++---++-+---+-++-----+-++++----+++-++++--+--+-----+-++++----++++-+++-+---+---+-+-++++-++---+-++-+-+-+++-+-+--+-----++-+++---+-++---+++-++-+--+++++------++---+-++++-+-+-+--++++-++++-+--+++-++---+-----++-+-++-+-+++--++-+-+-++-++-----+-++--+--+--+-------++--+-++-+--++-++-++--+-+-++-+-+++-++++-+---+--+++--++--+-+++++-+-----++--++--+++--++-+---++----+--+-+--++-++---+++++++-+--+-++---+----+-+-+--+-+-+--++++-++--+--+-+---+++-+++++++-++-+-----+--++------+-++++++--++-++-+---+-++---++-++------+-++--+-++-+++--+++-+++-+-+--+-+--+--+---+-+-+-+--+-++-+-++---+++-+-+-++--+-++-+---++--+-+--++-+++-+--+++---+----+--++-++++++-++-+----+++-+-+--+++-----+---+--++-+--+-++++++-+-+++--+++---+-+-++++-++-+-+----++++----+++-++----+---++-+---++-+-+-++--+++---+--+++----++-++-+++--+--+---+++--+--+--+--+--++++-++++---+-+-+--+-+-+--++++--+-+--++--++++----++-++++++-+--+-+------+-----+++----++-+++++-+--+--+---++-+-++-+--++++-+++---+++-+----+--+++++-+-+--+++--++-+++-+-++---++-++-+-+-+--+-++--+---+-+++--+++++-----+-++-+-+++-+-+-------++++---+-+-++-+--+++++---+--++-+-++-+++----+++-++++---++------+-+---++++--+-+---+++------++++++---++-+----+-+++-+--++-+-+-+-----+-++-++-++--++-+-+-++++++--++---+-+-+-+-+-+-++-++-++----++--++-+++-++---+++--+++---+++--+-+++----++--+-+-+++---++---++-+--+++++-+---++----++--+++-+--+-+++++++-+--+---+--+---+----+-++-++-+--++--+--++-++---+++++--+-+---+-++-+-+----+++-++-+-+--+---+-++-+-----++---++++--+++++-+---+-++--+-+-+----+--++++-+-----++++--++-+-+++++----+++---+++++++--+---+--+--++++--+++-----+-++--+-+-----+++++----+-++++---+-++--+-++-+++--+++-+-+++++--+----++--+--+-+-++-----++-+--++--++++++-+-+++----++++---++-+--+-+------+-+--+++++--+++--++-----+--++-++-+++++-++-------+----++-++--+--++--++++-++---+-+++++----+-++-++---+++---+-++-++----++--++--+++++-+--+-----+-+-+-+-+++-+--++-+-+++--+-+-+++-+-++--+-+-+-+--+-+-+++++---+---+-++-+---++-+-++-+-+++-++-++-+-++-------++---+-++-++++-++--++--+-++-+++---++++--+----+---+-++-+++--+-+++---+-++-++----+--+--+-++--+-++-++++++--+-++-+--+---+-+--+-+--++---+--+-++--++--+--++-++++----+--+--+++-+++-+-+-++--++-+-+---+-+-------+--++++++-++++++-++-+-++-+---+--+-+-++--+++---+----+--+--+-++----+-+-++-++-++-+++--++---++-------+++++--+-+++++++--+--+-+--++--++--++-+--+--+++----+++++-++-------++---+-+--++-++--+++-+-+-+-+------+-+--+++++-+-+--++-++-++--+++++++---+-++--+++-+++--++++-++--+-+---+----+----+---+--+-+++-+-+++++---+--++--+-+++-+++++--+---+-+++++-+---++++--+-++----+---++----+++---+++++-+-++--+--+-++-++----+---++-++-+-+-+---+++-++-+++-+---+++--+-+-----++-+---++-+---++---+-++--++++-+--++-+-++----+-+-+--++--++++--+--++--+--+-+-+++++++--++-+-+-+++--+---+++--++++++--+-+-----+---++-+++--+++--++---+++--+--+-++++-----+++-----++++--++--+-+--
Events occurred:   3061
Queued packets:    3061
Dropped packets:   0
Processed packets: 1464
Filtered (per source) 58 48 53 51 47 39 45 42 53 52 57 50 63 43 49 57 45 58 40 42 56 54 58 52 44 53 61 41 50 33 51 52 
Total filtered:   1597
Idle cycles:      26408166
```

The first line (`++-+++++++--+++-++++-++-+++---+`...) is a shorthand notation showing the number of *effective* changes in `source_enabled[]` flags.

You can see that at this rate, the queue is not saturated and the consumer thread has quite a number of idle cycles.

## Demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b0f44cbc5e932cd)

Full listing for reference:

```
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <thread>
static constexpr uint8_t NUM_SOURCES = 32;

namespace queueing {
    using data_t = std::vector<char>; // just for demo

    struct spsc_queue_item {
        uint8_t ID;
        data_t  data;
    };

    // process control
    boost::atomic_bool shutdown_flag { false };

    namespace statistics {
        namespace events {
            boost::atomic_size_t occurred  { 0 };
        }

        namespace packets {
            boost::atomic_size_t queued    { 0 };
            boost::atomic_size_t dropped   { 0 };
            boost::atomic_size_t processed { 0 };
            boost::atomic_size_t skipped[NUM_SOURCES] = {};
        }

        boost::atomic_size_t idle_cycles   { 0 };

        void report() {
            namespace stats = queueing::statistics;
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "Events occurred:   " << stats::events::occurred   << "\n";
            std::cout << "Queued packets:    " << stats::packets::queued    << "\n";
            std::cout << "Dropped packets:   " << stats::packets::dropped   << "\n";
            std::cout << "Processed packets: " << stats::packets::processed << "\n";

            std::cout << "Filtered (per source) ";
            std::copy(std::begin(stats::packets::skipped), std::end(stats::packets::skipped), 
                    std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(std::cout, " "));
            std::cout << "\n";

            auto total_filtered = std::accumulate(std::begin(stats::packets::skipped), std::end(stats::packets::skipped), 0ul);
            std::cout << "Total filtered:   " << total_filtered << "\n";
            std::cout << "Idle cycles:      " << stats::idle_cycles      << "\n";
        }
    }

    // business logic
    boost::atomic_bool   source_enabled  [NUM_SOURCES] = {}; // true:started (process) / false:stopped (skip)
    boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<spsc_queue_item, boost::lockfree::capacity<2048> > shared_queue;
}

void producer_thread() {
    using namespace boost;
    namespace stats = queueing::statistics;
    // generate random data packets or start/stop filter events

    using queueing::spsc_queue_item;

    mt19937 engine;
    auto gen_srce = bind(uniform_int<uint8_t>(0, NUM_SOURCES-1), ref(engine));
    auto gen_data = [&] {
        std::vector<char> v; 
        std::generate_n(back_inserter(v), engine()%1024, bind(uniform_int<uint8_t>{}, ref(engine)));
        return v;
    };
    enum kind_t { knd_data, knd_start, knd_stop };
    auto gen_kind = bind(uniform_int<uint8_t>(knd_data, knd_stop), ref(engine));

    queueing::data_t const empty {};

    // 
    struct event_t { kind_t kind; spsc_queue_item item; };
    auto gen_event = [&] {
        auto kind = static_cast<kind_t>(gen_kind());
        return event_t {
            kind,
            spsc_queue_item {
                gen_srce(),
                kind == knd_data? gen_data() : empty
            }
        };
    };

    // now that we can easily generate queue items, let's do so in a loop
    while (!queueing::shutdown_flag) {
        auto evt = gen_event();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(engine()%102400));

        switch(evt.kind) {
            case knd_data:
                stats::events::occurred++;

                if (queueing::shared_queue.push(evt.item)) {
                    stats::packets::queued++;
                } else {
                    stats::packets::dropped++;
                }
                break;
            case knd_start:
                {
                    bool expected = false;
                    if (queueing::source_enabled[evt.item.ID].compare_exchange_weak(expected, true))
                        std::cout << "+";// << static_cast<int>(evt.item.ID);
                }
                break;
            case knd_stop:
                {
                    bool expected = true;
                    if (queueing::source_enabled[evt.item.ID].compare_exchange_weak(expected, false))
                        std::cout << "-";// << static_cast<int>(evt.item.ID);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

void fake_process(queueing::spsc_queue_item const& item) {
    // pretend it takes time proportional to the amount of data
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(item.data.size()));

    queueing::statistics::packets::processed++;
}

void consumer_thread() {
    namespace stats = queueing::statistics;

    queueing::spsc_queue_item item;

    auto consume_pending = [&] {
        while (queueing::shared_queue.pop(item)) {
            if (queueing::source_enabled[item.ID])
                fake_process(item); // if filtering started, process 
            else
                stats::packets::skipped[item.ID]++; // if filtering stopped, skip 
        }
    };

    while (!queueing::shutdown_flag) {
        consume_pending();
        stats::idle_cycles++;
    }

    consume_pending(); // drain any remaining queued items, to avoid race with shutdown_flag
}

#include <cassert>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    // check no source_enabled flags are set at start
    assert(0 == count(begin(queueing::source_enabled), end(queueing::source_enabled), true));

    auto producer = thread(producer_thread);
    auto consumer = thread(consumer_thread);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    queueing::shutdown_flag = true;

    if (producer.joinable()) producer.join();
    if (consumer.joinable()) consumer.join();

    queueing::statistics::report();
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer. Now with a functional [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b0f44cbc5e932cd)

Comment: The recorded live-stream of me coding, testing & refactoring this is here: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/lockfree-queue-filtering-with-32-channels/